# Open new window using window.open() and run function on said opened window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am trying to generate a barcode in a new window and run the barcode generator on the new window but I cannot seem to generate said barcode in the new window. I tried using window.focus() but that does not seem to work. I would appreciate help with generating the barcode in the new window without making the barcode appear on the page where the script asks for use input.

```js
function doAll(value) {
  var newWin = window.open('', '_blank');
  newWin.document.write('<svg id="barcode"></svg>');
  newWin.focus();
  generateBar(value);
}

function generateBar(value) {
  JsBarcode('#barcode', value, {
    format: 'code128',
    displayValue: true,
    width: 1.8,
    height: 60
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Generate Barcode</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css@2/out/water.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.0/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    Enter Number: <input name="packageID" type="text" onchange="doAll(this.value)">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any function(s) you want to run must be available to the document in the new window. You'll need to use `document.write()` to write a `script` element into the new window that points to a `src` where the function is. Also, you don't need to end a `script` and then start a new one for every function you create - - they can both exist in a single `script`.

Comment: `JsBarcode('#barcode',`    This will see `#barcode` in the current document,  I believe you could pass the element instead, that you can grab from the windows document.

Answer (score 0):

`JsBarcode('#barcode',`

The selector here is going to be looking a `document.querySelector`, but looking at the source for JsBarcode is can accept an element, so what you could do instead is grab the element from your `newWin` and pass this to `JsBarcode` instead..

example..

```
function doAll(value){
  var newWin = window.open('','_blank');
  newWin.document.write('<svg id="barcode"></svg>');
  newWin.focus();
  var element = newWin.document.querySelector('#barcode');
  generateBar(element, value);
}

function generateBar(element, value){
  JsBarcode(element, value, {
    format: 'code128',
    displayValue: true,
    width: 1.8,
    height: 60
  });
}
```